# Firefox Popup WIndow from Command Line

Tags: command-line, firefox

Is there any way to run a Firefox popup window (no menus, no address bar, no bookmarks bar) from terminal on Ubuntu? My idea is to create desktop launchers of popular web apps like web.whatsapp.com; or mycompany.slack.com like a standalone Firefox instances. So that it looks like a GUI App, but actually, its only a URL loaded in a Firefox popup window.